# How to read large pandas dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 4300*4300 diagonally symmetric pandas dataframe with 1 as diagonal value.
It is a correlation matrix. I want to read half of this matrix and also the corresponding 2 column names associated with that value.

I have written  2 nested for loops to read values and columns names into 3 lists, 
but it takes long time. Is there any efficient way for this.

Expected output dataframe:

```
column1, column2, corr_val
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a [mcve]? Your dataframe can be 5x5 instead of 4300x4300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup

Produce correlation matrix

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=list('ABCDE')).corr()
df

          A         B         C         D         E
A  1.000000  0.309111  0.219242 -0.239779  0.253331
B  0.309111  1.000000  0.435033  0.475270  0.881688
C  0.219242  0.435033  1.000000  0.005637  0.394912
D -0.239779  0.475270  0.005637  1.000000  0.483238
E  0.253331  0.881688  0.394912  0.483238  1.000000
```

---

### Use `np.triu_indices`

```
i, j = np.triu_indices_from(df, k=1)

d = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    ROW=df.index[i],
    COL=df.columns[j],
    VAL=df.values[i, j]
))
d

  COL ROW       VAL
0   B   A  0.309111
1   C   A  0.219242
2   D   A -0.239779
3   E   A  0.253331
4   C   B  0.435033
5   D   B  0.475270
6   E   B  0.881688
7   D   C  0.005637
8   E   C  0.394912
9   E   D  0.483238
```

Comment: This is awesome and very fast! thanks a lot. I did not have index with column names so I had to add that. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome.